# Controlling flags passed to the generator

Tags: cmake

My project is bare metal, so I need to have a full control of the compiler/linker flags passed by cmake to the generator (ninja in this case). after setting seemingly everything, I still am getting `/SUBSYSTEM:console` passed to the linker which I haven't set (I do set another /subsystem value) in the ninja.build file. I checked CMakeCache.txt file so as to see, that all *_INIT variables were cleared/set appropriately by my "override" file, and they really are. I checked the target link options, the directory ones, there is no this option set over there, yet it's getting stubbornly passed. Where else I need to look to find what yet variable (they seem to be endless) is adding to the final linker options list? Thanks.

Edited. As asked, below is the minimal example for redproducing it:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE OFF)

set(CMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE "./overrides.cmake")

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")

project(MyProject)

if(ARCH STREQUAL "arm")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "/arch:ARMv7VE ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")
endif()

list(APPEND MyProjectSources
    source1.c source2.c source3.c
)

add_executable(MyProject ${MyProjectSources})
set_target_properties(MyProject PROPERTIES SUFFIX ".efi")

target_compile_options(MyProject PRIVATE    /kernel /X /Zl /GR- /EHs-c- /Gs65536 /GS- /TC /nologo)
target_link_options(MyProject PRIVATE   /NODEFAULTLIB /SAFESEH:NO /RELEASE /SUBSYSTEM:EFI_APPLICATION
                /ENTRY:LoaderEntry /FIXED:NO /GUARD:NO /MACHINE:${ARCH} /NOLOGO)
```

and here is the `overrides.cmake` file, mentioned in the above, main (and only) `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES_INIT "")

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT "")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT "")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT "")
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_LIBRARIES_INIT "")

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT "/debug")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO_INIT "/debug")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT "/debug")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO_INIT "/debug")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT "/debug")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO_INIT "/debug"
```

The resulting `ninja.build` file's linker options, have these 3 flags (prepended), in addition to what I've set:

```
/machine:ARM64 /INCREMENTAL:NO /subsystem:console
```

the 1st comes from `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`, the 2nd - from `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE`, and the 3rd comes from nowhere.

Comment: Are you using MSVC or ClangCL? Can you post your toolchain file? (I assume this is what you mean by "override")

Comment: The full list of variables is available here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html

Comment: Also, have you tried with the Visual Studio generator? It might be that Ninja doesn't support changing this setting.

Comment: That should be edited into your question. Please do not post long code snippets in the comments.

Comment: The various `LINKER_FLAGS` variables there should contain your alternate `/SUBSYSTEM` flag.

Comment: I tried only ninja. the compiler is MSVC. but why ninja doesn't allow to change that? is ninja suitable only for console programs? kind of doubtful.

Comment: No, CMake's support for MSVC through Visual Studio is much older and more mature and does a better job translating your custom settings into correct projects.

Comment: I set the needed subsystem through `target_link_options` and it gets added, but this one (which is a duplicate) is added too.

Comment: Can you post (by editing your question) the _exact_ compiler invocations CMake produces? Better yet, create a minimal example we (I) can use to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I use cmake/ninja, coming with VS. just without using the IDE itself (using command line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *believe* you can set `CMAKE_C_CREATE_CONSOLE_EXE` to `/SUBSYSTEM:EFI_APPLICATION` from your override file and it will work. **This variable is undocumented**, but there does not appear to be a better way to do this. I ***strongly*** suggest you ask the developers directly what to do here on [their Discourse](https://discourse.cmake.org).

---

Here's how I figured this out by looking through the CMake source code.

First, I cloned their repo and did `git grep -i "subsystem:console"` and found the following snippet:

```makefile
  if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "WindowsCE")
    set(CMAKE_${lang}_CREATE_WIN32_EXE "/entry:WinMainCRTStartup")
    set(CMAKE_${lang}_CREATE_CONSOLE_EXE "/entry:mainACRTStartup")
  else()
    set(CMAKE_${lang}_CREATE_WIN32_EXE "/subsystem:windows")
    set(CMAKE_${lang}_CREATE_CONSOLE_EXE "/subsystem:console")
  endif()
```

https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/09cf726f48cfa44f8822eac5b6bef8655f92059e/Modules/Platform/Windows-MSVC.cmake#L350-L356

Then I grepped for `_CREATE_CONSOLE_EXE` and found it is used by the generator to *unconditionally* add the flag to the executable flags, here:

```cxx
        if (target->IsWin32Executable(config)) {
          exeFlags += this->Makefile->GetSafeDefinition(
            cmStrCat("CMAKE_", linkLanguage, "_CREATE_WIN32_EXE"));
          exeFlags += " ";
        } else {
          exeFlags += this->Makefile->GetSafeDefinition(
            cmStrCat("CMAKE_", linkLanguage, "_CREATE_CONSOLE_EXE"));
          exeFlags += " ";
        }
```

https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/09cf726f48cfa44f8822eac5b6bef8655f92059e/Source/cmLocalGenerator.cxx#L1535-L1543

This happens pretty early in the link line, so later flags should override it. If `/SUBSYSTEM` overrides earlier copies of the same flag, you should not touch the undocumented variable.

Comment: thank you very much! unfortunately I can't yet upvote your answer. :) yes, this setting will be overridden by mine, I just was afraid, there might be cases, where it wouldn't be this easy resolved. having full control over the flag setting is the only means for being safe. which is not possible, as you've figured out in the case of CMake.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: Thank you. :)

I've checked, setting `CMAKE_<lang>_CREATE_CONSOLE_EXE` in the override (toolchain) file has no effect, the `/subsystem:console` flag is still present. despite, the variable really gets reset to `/subsystem:efi_application`. thankfully, the linker does accept multiple settings and the last one overrides the previous in this case.

Comment: I found the solution in this [blog](http://wenqiangwang.blogspot.com/2014/02/targeting-windows-xp-with-visual-c-2013.html). The idea is to use `set(CMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE_CXX "your_path/overrides.cmake")` and in file 'overrides.cmake': `if(WIN32)
 if(TARGETING_XP_64)
 SET(CMAKE_CREATE_WIN32_EXE "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.02")
 SET(CMAKE_CREATE_CONSOLE_EXE "/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE,5.02")
 elif(TARGETING_XP)
 SET(CMAKE_CREATE_WIN32_EXE "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.01")
 SET(CMAKE_CREATE_CONSOLE_EXE "/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE,5.01")
 endif()
 endif()`. See doc for `CMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE_<LANG>`.

Comment: Use `CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_CONSOLE_EXE` and `CMAKE_C_CREATE_CONSOLE_EXE` for CMake 3.21+, and `CMAKE_CREATE_CONSOLE_EXE` and `CMAKE_CREATE_CONSOLE_EXE` for early, also for `*_CREATE_WIN32_EXE`. See file 'share\cmake-<ver>\Modules\Platform\Windows-MSVC.cmake' for these variables.